# Help Identifying Experiment Design

Tags: experiment-design

I'm hoping for some help identifying the experiment design in this question:

*A large bakery would like to run an experiment that consists of evaluating the volume of their cupcakes after baking.  Four recipes among their many recipes are selected at random.  The employees and the owner of this bakery agreed on using three cooking temperatures.  It is desired to have six replications from each combination of the four recipes and the three cooking temperatures.  However, only twenty-four cupcakes can be baked per day, so the experiment must have to be spread over three consecutive days in order to achieve the six replications.  Six similar ovens, randomly chosen from the pool of all ovens, are available in the course of the entire experiment every day and each can bake four cupcakes at a time.*

The related question is

*Discuss in detail how you will implement such an experiment in light of the constraint(s) imposed.  Identify the design that you would use.*

I want to suggest a split-plot design with recipe as 24 the main treatment/whole plots, each divided into three temperatures (subplots/split-plots).  I believe this achieves significant experimental efficiency, rather than 72 total 'runs' to achieve the 6 replicates.  However, I'm not sure how to account for the 'similar' ovens in this design.

Should I consider a nested design?  Is blocking for the effect of oven necessary (I think 'no' because they are chosen at random)?  Or can I stick with the split-plot and effectively ignore the various ovens?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem,  thus this only a suggestion.If you have six replicates and six ovens then why not consider which oven as an additional experimental factor?

Comment: It's a practice question for an exam.  I think the issue with the general factorial design is that selecting one recipe at random, then one temperature at random, and then one oven at random will require 72 total runs.  Are you suggesting to use the replicates as blocks?

Comment: Correct, that is what I am recommending.  With 72 runs that is enough to run one run with every recipe, temperature and oven.  Also this will help for the blocking for the three days.

Comment: You have convinced me that a nesting or split-plot structure is not necessary, but I am still struggling to finalize the design.  If I think of this as a factorial experiment with three factors: recipe, temperature, and oven and days as a nuisance factor, then I won't achieve six replicates.  Or should I think of it as a factorial with two factors (recipe, temp) and two blocking factors (oven, day)?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't see how to lay out the design.  It's clear to me I can assign every recipe and temperature combination to all six ovens.  My problem is that each day can do 24 runs, which is two replicates of the 3x4 recipe/temp combinations.  I think the blocks per day should divide evenly (i.e., only 12 runs allowed per day), and I can't assign one oven per each day.  I can't put the pieces together here to continue on writing a model and outlining the ANOVA table.  Unless I 'ignore' the effect of oven, since it will 'average out'.  Then there is one block and two treatments.

Comment: Split-plot design. The ovens are the whole plots (units) and can only run at one temperature at a time, so only 6 runs per day at the whole-plot level. A hard-to-change factor. But within an oven you have 4 split-plots (sub-units) that can run the four different recipes, so 24 sub-units per day. The language of "randomly chosen from the pool of all ovens" hints that you're to treat ovens as random-effects blocks instead of fixed-effects blocks.  This might help: https://www.minitab.com/uploadedFiles/Content/News/Published_Articles/recognize_split_plot_experiment.pdf and ...

Comment: Follow-up article to the one I just linked to: https://www.minitab.com/uploadedFiles/Content/News/Published_Articles/analyze_split_plot_experiment.pdf

Comment: @MichiganWater, we cannot measure the effect of oven based on your design.  I had a colleague suggest that this is a spilt plot design with temperatures (fixed) and ovens (random) in the whole plots, where oven is nested under temperature, and recipe (random) as the sub-plots.  That is, it's both a nested and split-plot design.  I'm still uncertain because there is no language in the question to suggest we are not interested in the effect of oven.

Comment: 1/ How are you distinguishing between ovens and whole plots?  Based on your description (ovens in WP) it sounds like you're saying you'll have multiple ovens per whole plot? Everything I've ever read about split-plot designs says that the upper level treatment/hard-to-change factor (temp) is applied to WPs  You want to apply it at a sub-WP level (oven)?  I'm not sure how that would work, though my knowledge is certainly limited. Ovens/furnaces are a common illustration for split-plot examples.  I suggest a web search for those terms together and you'll get a number of hits.

Comment: 2/ Also, I should take back my comment about treating ovens as random effects. Under circumstances where you had lots of them, you could do that, but when you have a very small number, and 6 is on the small side, that could lead to convergence problems, and it's best to model them as fixed.  Either way, the interest is not usually in just those 6 ovens, but in any of the similar ovens that could be used, which is why I think of them in concept as random effects.  Would you want your modeling equation to include coefficients for each oven?  What happens if you want to use a new oven?

Comment: Err, it's oven _runs_ that are the whole plots (in my view), so 24 whole plots to which temp is applied to.

Comment: Sorry, it really doesn't help with your answer, but the "question" raises more questions. How is a "large bakery" with six ovens only capable of baking an extra two dozen cupcakes per day. In my home oven, I can bake three dozen cupcakes at a time. Just how small are these ovens that only 4 cupcakes can be baked at a time? This sounds like "10 year old child with 6 Easy-Bake ovens can only bake 4 cupcakes in an oven. They are using 60, 100, and 120 Watt bulbs. Only 24 cupcakes, or one batch per oven, can be baked per day." Also, what is the plan for measuring the volume of baked cupcakes?

Comment: @Tavrock, this is an old qualifying exam question for a statistics PhD program.  I agree the parameters of the question are absurd, but the goal is to create restrictions to require appropriate designs.  FYI, the consensus of my colleagues is that it is a ``bad" question or extremely difficult (split-plot design with nested subplots).  For what it's worth, I passed my quals.

Answer (score 1):

MichiganWater mention this is a split plot design, Temperature is the plot and the recipe is the subplot.

Using R to design the experiment:

```
library(agricolae)
library(tidyr)

Temp <- c("T1", "T2", "T3")
Recipe <- c("R1", "R2", "R3", "R4")
#Oven <- c("O1", "O2", "O3", "O4", "O5", "O6")

splitdesign <- design.split(Temp, Recipe, r=6, serie = 2)

#rearrange the table
answer <-pivot_wider(splitdesign$book, id_cols = "block", names_from="Temp", values_from="Recipe", values_fn = list(Recipe= toString))

answer
# # A tibble: 6 x 4
# block T3               T2               T1            
# <fct> <chr>            <chr>            <chr>         
# 1     R2, R1, R4, R3   R3, R4, R2, R1   R1, R2, R3, R4
# 2     R4, R2, R1, R3   R4, R2, R1, R3   R2, R1, R4, R3
# 3     R2, R4, R1, R3   R2, R1, R4, R3   R2, R1, R3, R4
# 4     R1, R3, R2, R4   R3, R2, R1, R4   R2, R3, R4, R1
# 5     R3, R2, R4, R1   R1, R4, R2, R3   R2, R3, R4, R1
# 6     R1, R4, R3, R2   R2, R1, R4, R3   R4, R3, R2, R1
```

In this case the block would represent the oven.  Thus to run the experiment each block would assign each temperature to a different oven.  For example: T3 block would run in oven 1 to 6 across all of the blocks, then T2 would run (3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2) and T1 would run (5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4) now each Treatment (Recipe & Temperature combination) would run in each oven an equal number of times (ie a balanced design).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perhaps the question that the OP quoted could be more clear, but I don't think your answer fits the parameters of the question. Each oven can bake 4 cupcakes at a time, and only 24 cupcakes can be baked per day, so there can only be 6 oven-level runs per day, otherwise it'd be possible to bake more than 24/day, yes? To me, this indicates a split-plot design with temp as a hard-to-change factor applied to oven run whole-plots, and recipe applied to cupcake split-plots, as described in my comments under the Question.

Comment: @MichiganWater, I completely missed the "each can bake four cupcakes at a time." line.  Yes the split plot design is probably best. See edits

Comment: Glad I was able to help add some clarity.  I tried running your code, but got this error during the call to pivot_wider: *Error: Input must be a vector, not NULL.*   Does the code as written above work for you?  I'm not familiar with pivot_wider (or the tidy universe), so I don't know how to troubleshoot why it might be wrong (on my computer, at least).

Comment: @MichiganWater, Sorry the function in `pivot_wider` should be `toString()` and not "cat"

Comment: Code works now.  +1 on the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  I agree it's a split-plot, but I think this solution here is missing the effect due to (1) ovens and (2) days.  I think one approach is to treat this as a split-split plot design, or to use nested whole plots - both of which are unpleasant.  For background, this a PhD qualifying exam question.

Comment: @Jackson, Thanks for the background.  It looked pretty straightforward at the straight but there were many details which complicated it.  I am encouraged that I at least cranked out at least a partially correct answer.